# Optimize the operation of retrieving user's location periodically android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, intentservice

I'm trying to develop an android app that will use google map and retrieve the user location every 5 minutes and display it on the map.

I have three questions : 
- How to schedule an intent service so that the location will be retrieve 5 minutes?
- Did my code is suitable to achieve this goal?
- How can I optimize battery usage with it?

Thanks 
Here is my code :

```
public class RetrieveActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

public static LatLng mCurrentLatLn = null;
MapFragment mMapFragment;
// The map used in MapFragment
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private String KEY_CURRENT_LAT_LONG = "KEY_CURRENT_LAT_LONG";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("safer", "onCreate ");
```

//        startService();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    buildToolBar();
    // Create a GoogleApiClient instance
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("safer", "onPause ");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mCurrentLatLn = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CURRENT_LAT_LONG);

}

/**
 * Utilitary method used to initialize our vars
 */
protected void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void buildToolBar() {
    // Handle Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        // Set the toolbar title
        TextView title = (TextView)     toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        title.setText(R.string.app_name);
        title.setTextSize(28.0f);


        // Set the toolbar navigation icon
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        // Use the toolbar as Actionbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    UiSettings uiSettings = mGoogleMap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
    uiSettings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
    uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (l != null) {
        mCurrentLatLn = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
        moveCameraTo(mCurrentLatLn);

    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

    if (mCurrentLatLn != null) {
        moveCameraTo(mCurrentLatLn);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(RetrieveActivity.this, "Please enable location service...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return true;
}

// Method to start the service
public void startService() {
    Log.d("safer", "startService ");
    startService(new Intent(RetrieveActivity.this, FetchingData.class));
}

private void moveCameraTo(LatLng position) {
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(position)
            .zoom(Constants.MAP_ZOOM_DEFAULT_LEVEL)     // Sets the zoom
            .tilt(Constants.MAP_TILT)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> How to schedule an intent service so that the location will be
>   retrieve 5 minutes?

Use AlarmManager and schedule a way to get the location by starting your service

> Did my code is suitable to achieve this goal?

You're not using AlarmManager , so **no**. Also just an FYI Handler is not ideal for longer period of times

> How can I optimize battery usage with it?

Use alarm manager it will batch requests as necessary which will save battery, but your requests may be delayed. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> How to schedule an intent service so that the location will be retrieve 5 minutes?

Intent service works for a particular task. You have to think when you need location! If your user stays on app and you need to show location on map again in every 5 minutes, you should do that in your activity. If a user is outside the app and you need to get the location, just use a Service and keep fetching location by making it wait 5 minutes. Also you can start Intent service again by using alarm manager and get the location!

> Did my code is suitable to achieve this goal?

Ask your user with a switch to turn this functionality off for good practices.By the way everything looks good!

> How can I optimize battery usage with it?

Although battery drains really fast when you do these kinda stuff.
Get the battery percentage and extend the time if its low! Do heavy stuff when user is charging there device or when they are not using in like after midnight!